# Excel: How to sum values associated with certain strings in different columns

Tags: string, excel, variables

Excel Example Image

[image]

Hi there! My problem is a little hard to describe so I hope the title isn't misleading.

As you can see in the image, there is a column of different 2-letter-strings with associated values in another column next to them. On the right there is another table with all the strings and a column next to it where I want Excel to sum all the values that are associated with that particular string.

So Excel has to basically scan trough the string column on the very left and check for "GE" for example. If it is successful in finding it, it has to refer to the cell in the same row that references the value and then add this value into the cell where it sums all the "GE" values.

I tried some different things already but I wasn't able to find a solution. I hope you can help me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) function. Enter it in every cell of column `G` where you want to see the result. As an example, `G3` cell should be:
`=SUMIF(B3:B12,"GE", D3:D12)`
**EDIT**: You could also pick the value from `F` column to avoid typos in the function, so you can also do it like:
`=SUMIF(B3:B12,F3, D3:D12)`

Comment: @DoomedtoConsume Cheers. I'm glad I helped. Thanks for the upvote/accept